# What does the brackets with comma around input arguments mean in python documentations?

Tags: python, code-documentation

What does the brackets around input arguments mean?

Consider this example:

`cv.boxPoints(box[,points])`
[example doc link](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf78d467e024b4d7936cf9397185d2f5c)

What confuses me the most is the comma inside the bracket of the second input argument points. Why is it represented as `[,points]`. Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a common convention in documentation to denote optional arguments with square brackets. That documentation is telling you that the second argument to `boxPoints` is optional. It has no syntactic meaning in Python; you can call the function with one or two arguments like normal.

Comment: Thanks for the response! any reason for the representing the args as `[,points]` instead of `,[points]`

Comment: @Mahesh Because if you don’t pass the `points` argument, you also don’t need to add the `,`.

Comment: hahaha wunderbar! makes most sense now.